# Extract entire addressbook name & number from ABperson objective c iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, abaddressbook

I need to know how to extract everyname & number from the address book in xcode for the iphone. I need to have the name and number in the following format:

John Doe:000000000000000 Jane Doe:000000000000000

Comment: I can just grab names i supply i cannot grab the whole list :/

Comment: Like we said yesterday in your deleted question, please post code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you searching for all phone numbers of all people in the address book? Look at [ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210-CH3-DontLinkElementID_3).

You could use it like this: (untested coded in browser)

```
    ABAddressBookRef _addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreate ();
    NSArray* allPeople = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(_addressBookRef);
    NSMutableArray* _allItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[allPeople count]]; // capacity is only a rough guess, but better than nothing
    for (id record in allPeople) {
        CFTypeRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)record, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        NSArray *phones = (NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phoneProperty);
        CFRelease(phoneProperty);
        for (NSString *phone in phones) {
            NSString* compositeName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName((ABRecordRef)record);
            NSString* field = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%@:%@",compositeName,phone];
            [compositeName release];
            [_allItems addObject:field];
        }
        [phoness release];
    }
    CFRelease(_addressBookRef);
    [allPeople release];
    allPeople = nil;
```

Comment: thank you i will test this out reads very well :) thanks for your time

Comment: how would i set the text of contacts a UITextView to the contacts pulled

Thanks again